# How to show PRINT results in EXCEL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms

A team member and I re-wrote a query we posted here due to issues; using various sources from provided answers from my previous question as well as checking other solutions and the query works now as intended. **HOWEVER** we need to embed this query and run in the background (we already have) into an EXCEL sheet but the issue is we need to somehow actually display the results in the cell. The **PRINT** function of the query actually pops up a window in EXCEL when we run (DUH, as intended) but what we would like to do is some how show the **PRINTED** results. Since the query is run automagically inside the spreadsheet the option to export from SSMS to a file then retrieve from there is not an option since OUR DBA is pretty funky on what we do with the DB we cannot run as a job..etc.... Any help again would be appreciated.

```
Declare @StartDate1 as DateTime
Declare @StartDate2 as DateTime
Declare @EndDate1 as DateTime
Declare @EndDate2 as DateTime
Declare @TodaysDate1 as DateTime
Declare @TodaysDate2 as DateTime
Declare @Yesterday as DateTime

Declare @TotalRecords1 int = 7
Declare @TotalRecords2 int = 7

set @TodaysDate1 = GETDATE()
set @TodaysDate2 = @TodaysDate1
set @Yesterday = DATEADD(day,-1,@TodaysDate1)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
--                For AM Shift Data Readings                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------
set @StartDate1 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Yesterday)) + ' ' +
    '17:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate1 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @TodaysDate1)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, getdate())) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, getdate())) + ' ' +
    '04:59' as datetime)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
--                For PM Shift Data Readings                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------
set @StartDate2 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Yesterday)) + ' ' +
    '05:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate2 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Yesterday)) + ' ' +
    '16:59' as datetime)

--------Material Scan Table--------

SELECT
@TotalRecords1=(SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate1 and @EndDate1), 
@TotalRecords2=(SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2) 

WHILE @TotalRecords1 = 0 AND @TotalRecords2 = 0

BEGIN
set @TodaysDate1 = DATEADD(day,-1,@TodaysDate1)
set @TodaysDate2 = DATEADD(day,-1,@TodaysDate2)
set @Yesterday = DATEADD(day,-1,@TodaysDate1)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
--                For AM Shift Data Readings                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------
set @StartDate1 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Yesterday)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Yesterday)) + ' ' +
    '17:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate1 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @TodaysDate1)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, getdate())) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, getdate())) + ' ' +
    '04:59' as datetime)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
--                For PM Shift Data Readings                     --
-------------------------------------------------------------------
set @StartDate2 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @TodaysDate2)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, getdate())) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, getdate())) + ' ' +
    '05:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate2 = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, @TodaysDate2)) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, getdate())) + '-' +
    convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, getdate())) + ' ' +
    '16:59' as datetime)

SELECT
@TotalRecords1=(SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate1 and @EndDate1), 
@TotalRecords2=(SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2)

IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate1 and @EndDate1) > 0
    BREAK
ELSE 
    IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Piston_TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] WHERE Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate2 and @EndDate2) > 0
    BREAK
    ELSE
    CONTINUE
END

PRINT '1st Shift LOT Trace Scans ending'
PRINT @EndDate2
PRINT @TotalRecords2
PRINT ' ' 
PRINT '2nd Shift LOT Trace Scans ending'
PRINT @EndDate1
PRINT @TotalRecords1
```

**THESE ARE THE ACTUAL RESULTS from run query in SSMS we would like to somehow get EXCEL to show:**

```
1st Shift LOT Trace Scans ending
Jul  6 2016  4:59PM
64

2nd Shift LOT Trace Scans ending
Jul  7 2016  4:59AM
73
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long weekend and help from the team we were able to get the results in EXCEL we want and pretty simple really. All we needed to do instead of PRINT was use CONCAT. I thought since we did eventually arrive at a conclusion I would post here. Though the answer above is also a somewhat solution the one I am posting here works more to our liking to avoid have to export the data when we can import automatically via the query. Thanks to all who chimed in!See bellow:

```
SELECT CONCAT ( '1st Shift  ', @StartDate1, ' Total Scans ', @TotalRecords1, ' and ' +
'2nd Shift ', @StartDate2, ' Total Scans ', @TotalRecords2 ) as LotTrace
```

**And the result was:**

```
LotTrace
1st Shift  Jul 11 2016  5:00PM Total Scans 105                      2nd Shift Jul 11 2016  5:00AM Total Scans 77
```

Comment: Your result doesn't even match with the expected outcome in your question. All `CONCAT` does is append strings together. You can `PRINT` or `SELECT` the resultant string.

Comment: My original question is we could not get the results of the query as a row so we could run from EXCEL sheet so how do we do this. PRINT results does not work when executing from within EXCEL. In order to get those results we ended up using the CONCAT to get it to appear as a row result named LotTrace in DB as well as EXCEL so we could then use the resulting data in further calculations in the spreadsheet that run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could try saving these into a table variable instead of printing them as follows:

```
declare @msgTable table ( msg varchar(100));
insert into @msgTable values ('1st Shift LOT Trace Scans ending');
insert into @msgTable values (@EndDate2);
select * from @msgTable;
```

and then right clicking the results and clicking `Save results as` to a `csv` file or a `tab delimited` file both of which you can open in excel.

Comment: Thanks, My shift ends soon so I will forward for team to try.

Comment: Since I couldn't sleep, I did just as you suggested and it works GREAT in the query. Working out one small issue populating to EXCEL as we want this query to automatically populate but this is a great response and getting closer to our end result!. Thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: `1st Shift LOT Trace Scans ending
 Jul  8 2016  4:59AM
 93`